# access environment variable set by a js file in a shell script

Tags: javascript, shell

In `deploy.sh` I have ,

```
sls deploy
echo "Incremented version is "
echo ${INCREMENTED_VERSION}
```

sls deploy has a post-deployment hook that executed a js plugin file that sets

```
    process.env['INCREMENTED_VERSION'] = incrementedVersion
```

Now, back to `deploy.sh`, If I try to access

```
echo ${INCREMENTED_VERSION}
```

It says unbounded variable. How do I get this value in the shell script?

Comment: Environment variables are inherited by child processes. They don't go back to the parent process. There's no way to send them up.

Comment: Right! I understand. There has to be a way to still access it in the parent script though. Any workarounds?

Comment: There are no workarounds. It is deliberately designed to be impossible for security reasons way back in the 70s and has been copied by every operating system inspired by the original Unix

Comment: Actually I guess there is a workaround. But it is so obvious that I don't think it is a workaround, just a different way of doing things. Instead of using the **wrong** mechanism (environment variables) use a config file or temporary file the old-school way

Comment: Take a look at how programs like `tset` work. They output variable assignment statements, and the calling script executes the output: `eval "$(tset ...)"`. If you can arrange for `sls deploy` to do the same thing you can use that mechanism.